# How can I see the mesh when I have vertices hidden in edit mode?

Tags: vertices

I don't have a mesh when I hide vertices, how can I turn it on?

When I hide vertices, I don't want to hide the mesh too, I want to see what I am editing(the mesh).

[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry but your question is not very clear, do you mean you made some vertices invisible? perhaps alt H ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please edit the question and clarify what you mean. It's OK if English is not your first language and you make mistakes. They can be corrected by other users, but you should try to explain it better so that it is possible to understand what you mean. Maybe try to say the same in different words a few times and explain the context a little bit.

Comment: Are you asking for hiding functionality for mesh elements? H to hide, shift+h to isolate selected, alt+h to show all hidden?

Comment: i mean when i hide vertices, i dont want hide mesh too, so i want to see what i editing(the mesh)

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit and it did not change the meaning you intended. If you don't like anything I corrected, please edit the question again.

Comment: Martin Z, Thank you, and sorry. Im new at the blender and this community, im young  so i trying to learn english so fast how i can, but it takes time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this functionality differs in 2.8 and 2.7 versions. Geometry modified with modifiers inherits the state of being hidden from the original mesh in 2.80:

[image]

There does not seem to be a way to achieve exactly what is shown in the video in 2.80 at least at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: I just found out as well. It seems to me it is probably kind of a new feature. This might not be that convenient in your situation, but that might be very useful when working with complex geometry while viewing modifier effects that might block the view of some parts of the mesh you wish to see. It probably makes more sense in other situations.